# ERROR: for app Cannot start service app: Invalid address : It does not belong to any of this network's subnets

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to the docker technology, i am trying to build an image on my local but keep having this error.

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Starting expensesservice_app_1 ...
Starting expensesservice_app_1 ... error

ERROR: for expensesservice_app_1  Cannot start service app: Invalid address xxx.30.0.9: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: Invalid address xxx.30.0.9: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Please how can i resolve this?

Comment: Did you do any manual configuration of the network or just letting docker-compose create the default one? docker and docker-compose versions?

Comment: Yes, there was a manual configuration. The expenseservice_app is a micro-service which communicates with a core application.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?